# Looking for a way to make mysite.com/product become mysite.com/product?userid=1 (WordPress site)

Tags: wordpress, url, dynamic, slug

I want all pages on my site containing /product in the URL to add a user id slug at the end of the URL automatically. It should be able to pull the user id assigned to the logged in user and add the user id to the URL. The page should be the exact same only with the user id at the end of the URL.

Ex) 
mysite.com/product -> mysite.com/product?userid=1 (when user 1 is logged in)
mysite.com/product  -> mysite.com/product?userid=2 (when user 2 is logged in)

Thinking something like this but I don't know PHP.

If - user is logged in
AND
if - page URL contains /product
THEN
get WordPress user id
AND
append user id to url

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will help you to achieve your needs, try it and let me know if it helps

```
function add_userid_product_page_url(){
    global $user_ID;
    if( is_user_logged_in() && is_page('product') && !isset( $_GET['userid'] ) ) : //Check User Logged In and Product Page and User Id not set in URL
        wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg('userid', $user_ID, get_permalink() ) );
        die;
    endif; //Endif
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'add_userid_product_page_url');
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for the assistance. I tried adding your code as a snippet using the code snippets plugin, however, it did not work. Maybe it would be easier to use the user's "username" on the account rather than the User ID??

Comment: Can you tell me what is the problem with this because this code is working as I have already tested, you can use username instead of User ID but it depends on how your further code has been done then you may do change with this code, I just created code as per your question

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure what the problem is. I don't know PHP. All I know is that when I put the code in my functions.php child theme it does not work. Here's my staging site: http://bke.1a0.myftpupload.com/

Comment: If I send you FTP info for my staging site, could you do it?

Comment: Ok will try please contact me personally @DougDemagistris

Comment: I reached out to you on Linkedin. If that does not work for you, how can I reach you?

Comment: Check LinkedIn I have sent you connect, do you get it or not

Comment: Yes! I received it. We're connected now.